# How Do I Open Purple Chests?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

What do I need in order to open the purple chests?

They say they are locked with a powerful magic. Just using Spring Lock on them doesn't do anything.

Comment: I'm not very far in, so my experience is limited to Ding Dong Dell. Are you referring to the chests like the ones that appear up the "fish staircase" and in the well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the fully restored Mornstar wand to open Purple Chests.

You'll have to defeat Khulan's Nightmare before you can talk to Khulan to perform the ritual to restore the Mornstar wand.

You first obtain the wand from an altar after defeating Candelabracadabra in the Tombstone Trail.

Comment: Thanks. I have the wand but I guess it's not fully restored yet. Who knew?